# ggplot, setting maximum number of x axis tickmarks

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

hopefully a trivial one. The code below is hopefully quite simplistic and is just to illustrate the issue (and hence is quite crude). I am just wondering what the best way to set a maximum number of x axis tickmarks might be here.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(year=c(2009,2009,2009,2009,2010,2010,2010,2010,
2011,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013,2013,
2014,2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2015),year_quart = c("2009-Q1","2009-Q2",
"2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2010-Q1","2010-Q2","2010-Q3","2010-Q4","2011-Q1","2011- 
Q2","2011-Q3","2011-Q4","2012-Q1","2012-Q2","2012-Q3","2012-Q4",
"2013-Q1","2013-Q2","2013-Q3","2013-Q4","2014-Q1","2014-Q2","2014-Q3",
"2014-Q4","2015-Q1","2015-Q2","2015-Q3","2015-Q4"),region = c("EU","EU",
"EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU",
"EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU","EU"),value = c(390,621,
442,113,586,571,391,432,758,897,696,160,189,567,621,922,402,185,609,812,549,
783,211,974,723,584,745,609))

plot1 <- ggplot(data, aes(factor(year_quart),value, xmin="2009-Q1", xmax="2009-Q4")) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=region),size=0.4) + 
  labs(x = "year", y = "value", title = "Title") + 
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks = unique(data$year_quart),
    labels = unique(data$year_quart),
    limits = c("2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2010-Q1","2010-Q2")
  )
```

So with this code I get a plot which looks OKish. However if I swap

```
limits=c("2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2010-Q1","2010-Q2")
```

with

```
limits=c("2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2010-Q1","2010-Q2","2010-Q3", "2010-Q4","2011-Q1","2011-Q2","2011-Q3","2011-Q4","2012-Q1","2012-Q2","2012-Q3",
"2012-Q4","2013-Q1","2013-Q2","2013-Q3","2013-Q4","2014-Q1","2014-Q2","2014-Q3",
"2014-Q4","2015-Q1","2015-Q2","2015-Q3","2015-Q4"))
```

I generate far too many tickmarks to be viewed clearly. So what I would ideally like is, for a certain year/quarter range, specific code that generates a maximum number of (clearly viewable) tickmarks depending on this range.

many thanks in advance!

Comment: I've edited your plotting code to be readable, and have removed the `theme` calls since those shouldn't be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If our goal is to make the tick labels more readable, we can always rotate them using the `axis.text.x` argument in `theme`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(factor(year_quart),value, xmin="2009-Q1", xmax="2009-Q4")) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=region),size=0.4) + 
  labs(x = "year", y = "value", title = "Title") + 
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks = unique(data$year_quart),
    labels = unique(data$year_quart),
    limits=c("2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2010-Q1","2010-Q2","2010-Q3", "2010-Q4","2011-Q1","2011-Q2","2011-Q3","2011-Q4","2012-Q1","2012-Q2","2012-Q3",
             "2012-Q4","2013-Q1","2013-Q2","2013-Q3","2013-Q4","2014-Q1","2014-Q2","2014-Q3",
             "2014-Q4","2015-Q1","2015-Q2","2015-Q3","2015-Q4")
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

[image]

Comment: that's a great suggestion, thank you. Realistically, though, I just want a maximum number of labels on the x axis, if at all possible and which would be determined by the year/quarter range selected. So if "aesthetically", say, 10 tickmarks was the visible limit and could be used with a largish year/quarter range, e.g. 2009-Q1 - 2015-Q4, then, conversely, if the first 9 year/quarter values, 2009-Q1 - 2011-Q1, were of interest, then 9 tickmarks would be drawn, etc. etc.

Comment: @ChrisS I don't quite understand what you mean by "visible limit". This is to me  quite subjective. Are you just trying to find a way to display only a range of tick labels but also show the whole plot?

Comment: yes, to update based on the year/quart range selected. I should add the code is basically a crude extract of a Shiny app of mine where this range is selected with dropdowns. I should also add that I would prefer a horizontal x axis text orientation. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisS So what is displayed should be determined entirely by the range selected and not the so called "visible limit", right? What you meant is the plot should expand or contract to accommodate the visibility of the labels, correct?

Comment: yes and with a maximum number of labels when the selected range results in overlapped labels

Comment: @ChrisS If that's the case I would just keep the ggplot as is and adjust the width of your plot depending on how many labels you have, with something like `output$timeseries_plot <- renderPlot({plot1}, height = 200, width = 300)` You can replace `300` with a multiplier on `length(range())` where `range()` is the selected range.

Comment: guess that would work if the minimum and maximum plot widths kept within the overall aesthetics (thanks!)